# jQuery Mobile 1.4+ Mobile widgets - native look and feel on devices iOS, Android WP8+

Tags: jquery-mobile

Do jQuery Mobile widgets supports the look and feel of native device like iOS7, Android and WP8+. Is there any way in the jQuery Mobile widgets Framework that will help to develop such widgets with the look and feel of native device?

By widget's the look and feel of native device, i mean on iOS7 device a widget like datepicker should open a in iOS7 style, it's interface for selection date be same as native iOS7 style. If same page accessed on Android it should look and feel like android's style.

Comment: you mean you want to prevent jQM from enhancing those widgets and keep them "native"?

Comment: Actually I want the whole page to look and feel like native on respective device(iOS, Android..). It's not only the datepicker widget. So jQM enhances it or don't may not matter.

Comment: Lets say a actionsheet widget, on android devices it is just open as pop up at center on device, while for iOS devices it slips up and stays bottom. Look is again different for both devices.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of answers here. First, the easiest thing for you to do is simply take your iOS device, open up mobile Safari, and go to jQuery Mobile. The site has online demos of all the widgets and you can see how things look.

Second - jQM automatically enhances widgets to look nicer on mobile, but if you do NOT want it to enhance, you can use a data attribute to tell jQM to leave it alone. So if you have input type=date and wanted the native date picker to fire, you could use that option. (FYI, it is data-enhance="false" on the page level, but you can also turn it off globally.)

Comment: On iOS7 and iOs6 devices the all widgets in jQM looks same. No difference. I want pages to look native to iOS7 / iOS6. If jQM enhances the widgets or give me hook to look them native, I would like either solution.

Comment: jQM updates widgets to have a uniform look and feel. If you want native UI then you may not want jQM.